# WP - difficulty with enqueueing scripts

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to add javascript files with `wp_enqueue_script`. The scripts do not seem to load at all in the page. What I have is::

```
function uberpasscode_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/bootstrap.min", array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min" );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uberpasscode_scripts' );
```

Comment: Where is the URL? Also, please screenshot or depict your theme directory structure.

Comment: @ham-sandwich http://brietsparks.net/

Comment: @ham-sandwich the main folder has all the templates, the theme stylesheet, and assets folder. The assets folder has the js folder, bootstrap, and an img folder

Comment: Found it my friend :-)

Comment: I added the .js, the console still shows no scripts being loaded :\

Comment: still no luck. I'll read up more on the basics (I'm a bit of a greenhorn) and revisit this thread later

Comment: I updated the answer. If this doesn't solve it I'm all out of ideas unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are missing the javascript (js) extension after .min.

```
function uberpasscode_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js", array('jquery'),'', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uberpasscode_scripts' );
```

Try adding those two parameters. Also, that version of jQuery you are trying to load is too old for bootstrap. Just use the jQuery built into WordPress. Also, make sure that you are putting this into `functions.php`

If this is still not working, please make sure you have the `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` function in your footer.php file.

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```